# Generate Barcode dynamically in Email Body/Attachment

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, html

I need to send emails to multiple contacts  with a bar code based on Customer ID in a pdf attachment.
The  requirement was to add the bar code in the attachment but due to salesforce limitation of accessing external images when rendered as pdf , made me modify the code to put the bar code in html email body.

I am using a third party freeware to generate the bar code , but still not able to generate barcode in the attachment.

Here is my vfpage mail template

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Account Info" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Account">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
Hi

Welcome to Stackexchange <br/>
Congratulations!
This is your Sample Email Template. <br/>
We are happy to provide you with the gift card <br/>
Kindly open the attachment for more details<br/>
<img id="theImage" src="http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code={!relatedTo.Cust_ID__c}&style=325&type=C128B&width=200&height=50&xres=1&font=3" />   
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
<messaging:attachment renderAs="PDF">
    <html>
    <head/>
    <body>
   <td> Hi {!relatedTo.name} </td><br/>
   {!relatedTo.Phone} <br/>
   {!relatedTo.Email_Address__c} <br/>
   {!relatedTo.Cust_ID__c} <br/>

    We are happy to provide you with the gift card
   </body>
    </html>
</messaging:attachment>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Note: I have added barcodesinc.com in Remoe Site Settings.

My query is how can we make the image available in the attachment

Currently its coming as a broken image.

Comment: That's a pretty cool utility. To think that I once wrote a barcode-generating visualforce component.

Comment: @sfdcfox, Can you please share your barcode-generating visualforce component code here.

Comment: @krishsfdc I'm pretty sure I have a copy of it somewhere, but I wrote it years ago. If I find it, I'll share.

Comment: @krishsfdc It was easy enough to write a "basic code 39 barcode", so I put it in a gist (see answer). It'd be pretty easy to expand it to include enhanced characters, I think.

Comment: For items like this I have used external pdf generators - pdfcrowd is one but not free, also http://www.spurdoc.com is another good one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remote site setting has nothing to do with the barcode appearing/not appearing.

Try the following:

```
<apex:image value="{!URLFOR('http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php', null, [code=relatedTo.Cust_Id__c, style=325, type='C128B', width=200, height=50, xres=1, font=3])}" />
```

I just tested this in my dev org with a standard field, and it works.

I suspect that your URL is getting confused because of unescaped characters, so this should fix it. You could also use URLENCODE.

---

I threw together some code that works in a PDF attachment, if you're *really* stuck. I've included the code [as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/b85fabe80f2ccd92abc383dfc0b33a89), but I'll also reproduce it here.

---

```
public class Code39Controller {
    // Determines if the check digit should be generated
    // If true, scanners must be enabled to use it
    public Boolean shouldCheckDigit { get; set; }
    // The source string to use. Currently only supports
    // the characters in the "keys" string. Do not use '*'.
    public String sourceCodeValue   { get; set; }

    // The index for supported characters.
    static String keys = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-. $/+%*';

    // The binary representation of each character, 16 bits each.
    static String[] values = new String[] {
        '1010001110111010', '1110100010101110', '1011100010101110', '1110111000101010',
        '1010001110101110', '1110100011101010', '1011100011101010', '1010001011101110',
        '1110100010111010', '1011100010111010', '1110101000101110', '1011101000101110',
        '1110111010001010', '1010111000101110', '1110101110001010', '1011101110001010',
        '1010100011101110', '1110101000111010', '1011101000111010', '1010111000111010',
        '1110101010001110', '1011101010001110', '1110111010100010', '1010111010001110',
        '1110101110100010', '1011101110100010', '1010101110001110', '1110101011100010',
        '1011101011100010', '1010111011100010', '1110001010101110', '1000111010101110',
        '1110001110101010', '1000101110101110', '1110001011101010', '1000111011101010',
        '1000101011101110', '1110001010111010', '1000111010111010', '1000100010001010',
        '1000100010100010', '1000101000100010', '1010001000100010', '1000101110111010' };

    // Renders the barcode on the screen
    public String[] getBarCodeBars() {
        return generateCode39(sourceCodeValue, shouldCheckDigit).split('');
    }

    // Returns a string in case we also want to debug the output.
    String generateCode39(String source, Boolean checkDigit) {
        // Output
        String[] result = new String[0];

        Integer index,      // Temp variable
                total = 0;  // Checksum calculation

        // Avoid System.NullPointerException
        source = source == null? '': source;
        // Start character is *
        result.add(values[keys.indexOf('*')]);
        // For each character in source
        for(String sourceChar: source.toUpperCase().split('')) {
            // Valid character, add to checksum and output bits
            if((index = keys.indexOf(sourceChar)) > -1) {
                result.add(values[index]);
                total += index;
            }
        }
        // Add the check digit
        if(checkDigit) {
            result.add(values[Math.mod(total, 43)]);
        }
        // Add the stop character
        result.add(values[keys.indexOf('*')]);
        // Join as string
        return String.join(result,'');
    }
}
```

---

```
.blackbar, .whitebar {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1cm;
}
.blackbar {
    background-color: black;
}
.whitebar {
    background-color: white;
}
```

---

```
<apex:component controller="code39" access="global">
    <!-- global required to use in templates -->

    <apex:attribute assignTo="{!shouldCheckDigit}" type="boolean" name="checkDigit" default="false" description="True if should append additional check character." />

    <!-- codeValue must be supplied, but cannot be required because of global attribute -->
    <apex:attribute assignTo="{!sourceCodeValue}" type="string" name="codeValue" description="The string to encode." />

    <!-- style sheet must be included to work properly -->
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.barcodeCSS)}"/>

    <!-- leave some space on the side for scanners -->
    <div style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid black; min-width: 1in; padding: 0.25in 1in;" >
        <div>
            <apex:repeat value="{!barCodeBars}" var="bar">
                <apex:outputText value="" styleClass="{!if(bar='1','blackbar','whitebar')}" />
            </apex:repeat>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <!-- we'll show the output text on the bottom, too -->
            {!sourceCodeValue}
        </div>
    </div>
</apex:component>
```

---

I used it in an email as follows:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Account Info" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Account">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
Hi

Welcome to Stackexchange <br/>
Congratulations!
This is your Sample Email Template. <br/>
We are happy to provide you with the gift card <br/>
Kindly open the attachment for more details<br/>

</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
<messaging:attachment renderAs="PDF">
    <html>
    <head/>
    <body>
   <td> Hi {!relatedTo.name} </td><br/>
   {!relatedTo.Phone} <br/>

    We are happy to provide you with the gift card<br /><br />
    <c:barcode39 codeValue="{!relatedTo.AccountNumber}" />
   </body>
    </html>
</messaging:attachment>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: I tried as suggested but still getting the same broken image for the barcode :(

Comment: @MaxPyne perhaps field level security? are you sure you can see the field's contents?

Comment: Yes..I doublechecked the FLS for Cust_Id__c and its set to be visible.

Comment: @MaxPyne Can you check the source of the email that was sent? What does the URL look like? Does it work if you go to the template and select "send and verify merge fields"?

Comment: Yes..In send Test and Verify where i have used the below markup the bar code is accurately generated

<img id="theImage" src="http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code={!relatedTo.Cust_ID__c}&style=325&type=C128B&width=200&height=50&xres=1&font=3" />

Comment: Can you paste your vf email template code which was working for u in ur dev org?

Comment: `<messaging:emailTemplate subject="barcode" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Account">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<apex:image value="{!URLFOR('http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php', null, [code=relatedTo.AccountNumber, style=325, type='C128B', width=200, height=50, xres=1, font=3])}" />
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>`

Comment: This is working for me as well....I was wondering for a solution for  pdf attachment with the bacode to be visible in the attachment..
I tried this but not working

 <messaging:attachment renderAs="PDF">
  <html>
  <head/>
  <body>
    <td> Hi {!relatedTo.name} </td><br/>
    {!relatedTo.Cust_ID__c} <br/>
    <apex:image value="{!URLFOR('http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php', null, [code=relatedTo.Cust_ID__c, style=325, type='C128B', width=200, height=50, xres=1, font=3])}" /> 
    </body>
  </html>
 </messaging:attachment>

Comment: @MaxPyne I added a custom component answer to this one. I definitely got *this* one to work, so feel free to try it out.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox - The code worked like a charm...I was looking for something simmilar to generate barcode logic internally in salesforce...you are a lifesaver :)